# Creating an array of System.ValueTuple in c# 7

Tags: c#

In my code I have:

```
private static readonly ValueTuple<string, string>[] test = {("foo", "bar"), ("baz", "foz")};
```

But when I compile my code, I get:

```
TypoGenerator.cs(52,76):  error CS1026: Unexpected symbol `,', expecting `)'
TypoGenerator.cs(52,84):  error CS1026: Unexpected symbol `)', expecting `)'
TypoGenerator.cs(52,94):  error CS1026: Unexpected symbol `,', expecting `)'
TypoGenerator.cs(52,103):  error CS1026: Unexpected symbol `)', expecting `)'
TypoGenerator.cs(117,42):  error CS1525: Unexpected symbol `('
TypoGenerator.cs(117,58):  error CS1525: Unexpected symbol `['
```

What is the correct way to create and initialize an array of ValueTuples?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try to create an instance of array with `new` and instances of tuple with `new` keyword

```
private static readonly ValueTuple<string, string>[] test = new ValueTuple<string, string>[]{
        new ValueTuple<string, string>("foo", "bar"), 
        new ValueTuple<string, string>("baz", "foz")
};
```

or with C#7 tuple syntax

```
private static readonly ValueTuple<string, string>[] test = new ValueTuple<string, string>[]{
        ("foo", "bar"), 
        ("baz", "foz")
};
```

*Update:*

Right now all declarations from the question and this answer works fine with Rider 2017.1 build #RD-171.4456.1432 and .NET Core 1.0.4. The simplest one is that @ZevSpitz mentioned in comments and it looks as follows:

```
private static readonly (string, string)[] test = {("foo", "bar"), ("baz", "foz")};
```

There is no need to add specific type for `ValueTuple`. Notice that for .NET Core the NuGet package `System.ValueTuple` has to be installed.

Comment: That fails with 

`TypoGenerator.cs(53,18):  error CS1026: Unexpected symbol `,', expecting `)'
    TypoGenerator.cs(53,25):  error CS1026: Unexpected symbol `)', expecting `)'```
    TypoGenerator.cs(54,18):  error CS1026: Unexpected symbol `,', expecting `)'
    TypoGenerator.cs(54,25):  error CS1026: Unexpected symbol `)', expecting `)`

Comment: @Lett1 Both examples work on [.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/MEPPd3). Have you tried example with `new` for array elements?

Comment: turns out that the c#7 tuple syntax wont work with rider on osx yet but the first solution works fine.

Comment: In C# 7, I don't think you need to use the `ValueTuple` name, either in the field definition, or in the `new` array expression -- `private static readonly (string, string)[] test = new [] { ("foo","bar"), ("baz", "foz")};`

Comment: Thank you @ZevSpitz there were some issues with this syntax couple of month ago, as OP mentioned. Right now it works fine, so I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 11):

Three short examples of using C# 7 syntax of array ValueTuple declaration & initialization:

```
(int Alpha, string Beta)[] array1 = { (Alpha: 43, Beta: "world"), (99, "foo") };
(int Alpha, string Beta)[] array2 = { (43, "world"), (99, "foo") };
(int, string)[] array3 = { (43, "world"), (99, "foo") };   // Item1, Item2, ...
```

These all compile fine on VS2017

Linq can be a good way to create arrays of ValueTuples, also:

```
var foo = Enumerable.Range(1,10).Select(z=> (Alpha: 43, Beta: "world")).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 3):

You can create a new tuple like this

```
var logos = new (string Name, string Uri)[]
{
    ("White", "white.jpg"),
    ("Black", "black.jpg"),
};
```

Comment: Can you explain a bit what you're doing here?